# Kubbuntu update to 20.04: Text fields are grey on black, can't see symbols

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

I upgraded to Kubuntu 20.04. Looks like everything went fine except the following problem, which renders my Laptop unusable.
Text field in setting and the  'control bar' (Fensterleiste) are grey on black. Therefore I can't choose anything, as it is unreadable. In the system settings for the design I just see black bloxes.

[image: What I see in system settings for the plasma design]

Edit: Added the screeshot in the dark breathe theme:
[image]

Edit2: a screenshot of the fonts dialog
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107356/discussion-on-question-by-peter-kubbuntu-update-to-20-04-text-fields-are-grey-o).

Answer (score 0):

After having spent a day on the problem, I made a fresh install.
Now I can see all icons. Even my /home survived the install and I jsut have to adapt a few settings that went lost (keyboard, wlan passwords, vpn).